# Окончание причастия

Tags: согласование, причастия

Какую форму причастия (из перечисленных в скобках) правильно употребить в данном предложении?

*Какой бульвар получил своё имя благодаря названию водоема, ранее (**именовавшимся, именовавшемся,
именовавшегося, именовавшемуся**) Поганым?*

Comment: А свои предположения есть?

Comment: Мы склонялись к варианту "именовавшегося", а Учитель русского языка в школе сказал, что "именовавшимся" , а я не могу с ней согласиться.

Comment: Учитель неправ.

Comment: Учитель сказал (м.р.), но а я не могу с ней (ж.р.) согласиться (?!)

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы упростить решение этой задачи и аналогичных, можно порекомендовать такой порядок действий:

1. Найдите существительное, к которому *по смыслу* относится действие, выраженное причастием.
2. Определите падеж этого существительного (оно здесь в правильном падеже).
3. Определите падежи вариантов вашего причастия (в данном случае среди вариантов есть верный).
4. Выберите то причастие, падеж которого совпадает с падежом существительного.

Answer (score 2):

В данном предложении причастный оборот расположен после определяемого слова и должен согласоваться с ним в роде и падеже.

*Какой бульвар получил своё имя благодаря названию* (чего? — Р. п.) ***водоема***, ранее **именовавшегося** Поганым?

Возможен другой вариант:
*Какой бульвар получил своё имя благодаря* (чему? — Д. п.) ***водоему***, ранее **именовавшемуся** Поганым?